# How to trigger a certain shell script on multiple Linux machines simultaneously?

Tags: linux, shell, triggers

I have a batch script which has to trigger a certain shell script on some 10 linux machines through plink[putty].
But when I trigger the shell script, the problem is that the control goes to shell script.It runs for some 10 hours and then returns the control to batch. Now my batch proceeds for the 2nd linux machine and wait for 10 hours and so on...

My requirement is to trigger the shell script on all the linux machines simultaneously.

It can be something like trigger the shell script return the ctrl to batch trigger on other machine also ok.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `bash` as your shell, you should include a tag for it. (Note the relatively low number of 'followers' for your tags.)

Assuming a modern Linux/Unix shell, the answer to you question is to append the `&` character to the line that makes the connection to the remote machine. `&` means 'run this process in the background'.

So something like

```
#!/bin/bash 
# master script
ssh host1 "/path/to/remote/script/runMe" &
ssh host2 "/path/to/remote/script/runMe" &
ssh host3 "/path/to/remote/script/runMe" &
ssh host4 "/path/to/remote/script/runMe" &
```

Sounds like what you are looking for.

Capturing log information and monitoring the status of the remote "runMe"s is in the realm of consultation engagments or at least 100 hrs of experimentation on your part. Good luck.

IHTH

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel you can do:

```
parallel --nonall -S host1,host2,host3,host4 /path/to/remote/script/runMe
```

GNU Parallel guarantees the output from stdout and stderr is captured and not mixed. With --tag each line will be prepended with the host:

```
parallel --tag --nonall -S host1,host2,host3,host4 /path/to/remote/script/runMe >output.stdout 2>output.stderr
```

To learn more watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

10 seconds installation:

```
wget -O - pi.dk/3 | bash
```